# Why is Eclipse displaying the lib folder in the Referenced Libraries list when I add a certain jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I wrote a Java program in Eclipse and exported it to a runnable jar called sslogger.jar.  I use this jar in various other Java projects.
I created a second project (project2) and copied sslogger.jar into the lib folder of project2.  When I add the jar to the project using 
Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add Jars... it displays an "extra" lib folder with the list of jars.  I have tried deleting the sslogger.jar from the lib folder and using the "Add External Jars..." option, but I get the same results.
I have a third project that also uses sslogger.jar (copied to the third project's lib folder) and it does NOT display the lib folder.  Project2 runs fine and the "extra" lib folder has no negative effects on the project, but it seems strange to display the "extra" lib folder.  Other programmers use the sslogger.jar and have experienced the same problem.  We use SVN version control.  Any ideas why this is happening would be helpful.

[image: Eclipse IDE lib folders]

Here is the .classpath file:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar"    
        sourcepath="lib/netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/scala-library-2.10.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-simple-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/scala-library-2.10.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/metrics-core-2.1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org-apache-commons-codec.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/sslogger.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con"  
       path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the project's .classpath file?